# STM32L476 LCD configuration and display

Tags: stm32, lcd, hal

I have configured my board using STM Cube, including LCD pins. Everything is in green, so i supose it's good. Now i want to display some data using the code below. But no matter what i put in "Data" LCD display no-sense things.

```
HAL_LCD_Init(&hlcd);
uint32_t counter = 0;
for(counter = LCD_RAM_REGISTER0; counter <= LCD_RAM_REGISTER15; counter++)
{
    HAL_LCD_Write(&hlcd,counter,RegMask,Data);
}
HAL_LCD_UpdateDisplayRequest(&hlcd);
```

And what should be putted in RegMask? It seems to doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that Hal lcd libraries is not for the lcd on the board. I have tried to use BSP libraries included to the demonstartion source (you can find it in stm cube repository). So if you will have the same problem as me - use BSP. It is very easy to use (translates direclty from string).